# how to return a 404 page if the data being requested isn't available on the database?

Tags: php

I have tried something like this, but it doesnt seem to work

```
if (empty($ArtID2)) {
   header("location: error?not-found");
} else { Run Code to fetch }
```

Comment: it should be  `header("Location: error.php?not-found");`

Comment: thankyou for your answer, but i have my server setup with an htaccess to get rid of the file extensions!

Comment: Then still, location should be capitalised, right?

Comment: It should? I'm pretty new to PHP so I'm not really sure about that. Sorry!
And by capitalised, do you mean "LOCATION"?

Comment: @John Mercel not `LOCATION` it is `Location` check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to solve the issue like this, but im not sure if its the best way to do it.

On the header, right after declaring the connection to the database, i added this code

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE art_id='$ArtID'";
$res = $conn->query($sql);
while ($rows = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Validation = $rows['art_id'];
}

if (empty($Validation)) {
    header("location: error?not-found");
}
```